# Complex fuzzy string matching in iOS

Tags: ios, regex, string, sqlite, search

I'm writing an iOS application that pulls events from a public Google calendar, pulls out the free-form "Location" field, and drops a pin on a map corresponding to the given location. I want to make the app as flexible as possible using some kind of string search or fuzzy matching algorithms, but I'm not sure where to begin.

There are several things a calendar moderator may enter into the Location field:

- A building name and room number (e.g. Foo Hall Room 123)
- A building abbreviation and room number (e.g. FOO 123)
- A shorthand room or location name (e.g. Foo)

Currently, I have a sqlite database composed of one table, each row storing a latitude, longitude, full building name (Foo Hall), and standardized building abbreviation (FOO).

I want to take the moderator's free-form string and obtain the correct coordinates from the database (if present).

I've tried using `LIKE '%FOO%'` and similar patterns, as well as Levenshtein Distance, but I run into issues, for instance if the actual building name is "Example Foo and Bar Building" and the location entered by moderator is "Example Bar Building".

The three options I've considered are...

- Force the moderator to enter in a standardized abbreviation or building name. This could potentially be a tedious process for the calendar moderators, so I'm trying to avoid this if possible.
- Do a crude substring search that checks if the entered string is contained anywhere in the database string. This is what my university does on their website, but it obviously isn't very flexible.
- Implement a more complex fuzzy string matching algorithm that provides maximum flexibility but will take an order of magnitude more time to implement. If the right one already exists, that would be the ideal solution!!

Which of these options (if any) seems the best? Is there a better alternative that I haven't thought of? Is there a library that does what I need and I just haven't found it yet?

Thanks in advance for any help!